# Parse Exception while trying to convert date from US/Eastern timezone

Tags: java

Here is the code to parse date and it throws parse exception. Can anyone help to resolve this? I do not want to use any other third party API.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ssZ");
    Date newDate;
    try {
        newDate = df.parse("28-04-2016 23:59:59 US/Eastern");
            df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            String strdate = df.format(newDate);
            System.out.println("The date and time in :: UTC is ::" + strdate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Getting exception is like below:  java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "28-04-2016 23:59:59 US/Eastern"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
 at com.turn.test.LongToDate.main(LongToDate.java:31)

Answer (score 0):

the Timezone handlling in simple java APIs are not that straightforward and thats why Java included JODA time with Java 8. In order to acheive your problem you can do something like below:

```
String sourceDateTimeTz = "28-04-2016 23:59:59 US/Eastern";
    String sourceDateTime = sourceDateTimeTz.substring(0, 19);
    TimeZone sourceTz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(sourceDateTimeTz.substring(20));

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    Date sourceDate;
    try {
        sourceDate = df.parse(sourceDateTime);
        Calendar sourceCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        sourceCalendar.setTime(sourceDate);
        sourceCalendar.setTimeZone(sourceTz);

        Calendar targetCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        for (int field : new int[] { Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.HOUR,
                Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.MILLISECOND }) {
            targetCalendar.set(field, sourceCalendar.get(field));
        }
        targetCalendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date targetDate = targetCalendar.getTime();

        System.out.println(df.format(targetDate));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```